# Level shifting with a voltage reference of 1.6V

Tags: level-shifting, voltage-reference

I am trying to build a level shifting circuit for my project in order to make sure that the input will be appropriate for a 0-3.3V ADC.

I am using two 9V batteries connected in series so my thought is that I have to shift the incoming signal by around 1.6V in order to be in range for ADC.

I have tried two ways to create a voltage reference using 4 1n5818 diodes in series that gave me a reference of around 1.8V and a LM317l voltage regulator giving me around 1.66V.

The problem in my schematic is that the when I connect the reference circuitry to the opamp, it doesn't work as expected. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work as expected", what exactly are you seeing? (Also, what op amp are you using?)

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy hello, when i connect the diode circuit as the voltage refence, there is an no offset at all and the output waveform is the same with the input. however when I connect the voltage regulator, there is an offset but the output is a straight line instead of a waveform. I am using a LMC6484

Comment: The behavior, as you say is not what is expected. My first guess would be mis-wiring somewhere. Are you doing this on a bread-board? Can you post a picture?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy yes, i am using 100kΩ instead of 75k here and 10kΩ instead of 50k

Comment: @dys_atlantis -- in your photo, I don't see how Vref is hooked up. also is that the same yellow wire on the bottom right looping around out of picture and coming back?

Comment: The resistor from 22 to 25, bottom side in image, seems to be misplaced? shouldn't one end be connected to op-amp input?

Comment: @PeteW yes the yellow wire connects the middle of the resistors to the output of the vref. I had to cut the picture to fit sorry about that

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy that is the first resistor that will be connected to the incoming signal,  it is then connected to another resistor that goes to the input of the op amp

Comment: 1) it appears to be connected to the wrong side of the voltage reference input resistor. 2) If you have two resistors connected in series for the input signal, then it is the combined resistance that should match the voltage reference input resistor.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy yes! i did have that connection wrong, thank you. I am not sure what you mean in the 2) note if you could explain what you mean and how that applies in the circuit

Comment: In your schematic you have 2 75k resistors connected to the non-inverting input of the op amp. In your image there are 10 100k resistors (one not tied directly to the op amp, but you are fixing that.) However, in your comment, it sounded like you were going to add yet a third resistor from your input to one of the 100k resistors. Maybe that is not what you meant. Anyway, if you added a third resistor, then the resistance from the signal to op amp would not match the resistance from the reference to the op amp. You would get voltage shifting _plus_ amplification/attenuation.

Comment: What's the range of the input signal? What kind of sensor is it coming from? What's its output impedance?

Answer (score 0):

1. Where you indicate you are connecting to the diode string is not the right place. It should be between the anode of the top diode and the current limiting resistor.
2. What is the signal source? Specifically, what is its output impedance? This appears as an additional resistor in series with the 75 K going off to the left (please add reference designators to your drawing), and affect both the overall circuit gain and the value of the DC voltage added.
3. The non-inverting input of your opamp circuit is not a virtual ground, so there is interaction between the input and offset signals.  The two 75 K resistors form a voltage divider for both.  This will attenuate *both* the input signal and the DC offset voltage (assuming the input signal reference potential is GND).

Comment: re: (3) -- If the source impedance isn't too high, it seems like an okay summation circuit. Positive input is (Vin + Vref)/2 , and output is 2x that.

Comment: thank you! could you explain how I can fix the gain? Do I just take the second 75k resistor out?

Comment: a) which one is the "second" one?  b) Doesn't matter; removing either one will not solve the problem.  c) Nowhere do you way how much gain you need.